# WebDriverWait behaves differently when debugging

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Started working with Selenium WebDriver. WebDriverWait is working fine when I **run** my tests, but I'm getting:

> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException 
>   {"no such element: Unable to locate element:
>   {\"method\":\"id\",\"selector\":\"exampleInputEmail1\"}\n 
>     (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)\n
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923
>       (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),
>       platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)"}

when I **debug** the tests.

Here's the code that fails:

```
Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl($"{BaseUrl}user/login");
var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.Id("exampleInputEmail1")));
```

The last line throws.  If I add a 30ms sleep, like so:

```
Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl($"{BaseUrl}user/login");
Thread.Sleep(30);
var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.Id("exampleInputEmail1")));
```

it works in the debugger too. Why would they be different?   I tried to search, but didn't find anything related to run v debug results. Thanks for any pointers.

Relevant details:

- Visual Studio 2015
- using Resharper 9.2 to run the tests under NUnit
- referencing WebDriver and WebDriver.Support 3.0.0

Comment: The 3 seconds timeout is probably too low. try to increase it to 25s: `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(25)`

Comment: I tried that with 100s.  Though the page should return at the same speed, since it doesn't know that i'm debugging.  But i will say that it's definitely NOT waiting in debug mode, because it fails immediately.

Comment: I have the same problem, though it's sometimes intermittent. The only way I can see to bypass it currently is to create a breakpoint when the WebDriverWait object is instantiated. Once the elements exist, pass the breakpoint.

Comment: This SO question seems to indicate that when VS is debugging, it throws a handled exception: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341620/webdriverwait-exception-only-thrown-in-debug-mode