# WebDriverWait Exception only thrown in Debug Mode in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, exception, selenium-webdriver

I was wondering if anyone else has encountered a similar problem like this or has experiences using WebDriverWait?

If they would know why I get a NoSuchElementException which seems to **only be thrown in debug mode**. I don't get this error being thrown when running the test in normal runtime.

I am able to click continue and step past the exception also.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is a quirk of Visual Studio's debug mode. Essentially in debug mode exceptions are sometimes treated as a break even if it is appropriately handled within a try/catch.

Remember when you pass a func to Until() in WebDriver, that func is executed internally within a try. VS is likely hitting the (handled) exception in that method, which is why you do not see it during normal running.

See [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/ceaf3da79542024becdda5953059dfbb96fb3a90/dotnet/src/support/UI/DefaultWait%7BT%7D.cs) for more info.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a workaround, for example if you are trying to find an element:

```
wait.Until(driver => driver.FindElement(
    By.CssSelector(".cssClass"))
);
```

You can do this:

```
wait.Until(driver => driver.FindElements(
    By.CssSelector(".cssClass")).FirstOrDefault()
);
```

And it will work on both release and debug environments.